# NEST Group With Count

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

How do you return group with counts using NEST client that returns only a paged result:

```
        ElasticClient client = GetEsConnection(); //ignore the details
        var searchResult = client.Search<Activity>(s=>s
        .Index(ElasticSearchConstants.EntityActivitiesIndex)
        .Type(ElasticSearchConstants.EntityActivitiesType)
        .Query(q=>q.ConstantScore(cs=>cs.Filter(f=>f
        .Bool(b=>b
        .Must(GetActivitiesQuery(request))))))
        .Fields(fields)
        .Sort(ss=>ss.Descending(sortBy))
        .Skip(0)
        .Take(10));
```

On the above example Activity has a property called ActivityType and I want to return a summary count for each activity type. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use `Terms aggregation` on the field `ActivityType`. See the usage of terms aggregation using Nest [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/terms-aggregation-usage.html).